# How to drag and drop rows with datatables.net-vue3

Tags: vue.js, datatable, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to implement drag and drop functionality at my `datatables.net-vue3`.I have already installed de dependency: `datatables.net-rowreorder-bs5`

This is my components code:

```
<template>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 offset-lg-2">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <DataTable 
                    ref="table"
                    :data="orders"
                    :columns="columns"
                    :options="{
                        responsive: true, 
                        rowReorder: {
                            selector: 'tr',
                            snapX: true,
                            enable: true,
                            update: true,
                        },
                        ordering:false,
                        searching:false,
                        lengthMenu: [ 10, 20, 30 ],
                        select: true,
                    }"
                    @row-reorder.defer="onRowReorder"
                    class="table table-stripped table-bordered display">
                    <thead>
                        <tr><th>#</th><th>ORIGEN</th><th>DESTINATION</th><th>ID</th></tr>
                    </thead>
                </DataTable>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import {mapState} from 'vuex';
export default{
    data(){
        return{
            columns: [
                {data: null, render: function(data, type, row, meta)
                {return `${meta.row+1}`}},
                {data: 'origin.street'},
                {data: 'destination.street'},
                {data: '_id'},         
            ],
        }
    },
    mounted(){
        this.$store.dispatch('orders/fetchOrders');
    },
    computed:{
        ...mapState('orders', ['orders'])
    },
    methods:{
        onRowReorder(event) {
            var table = event.target;
            console.log(event)
            var newData = table.rows().data().toArray();

            // Update the data for the row that was moved
            var movedRow = newData[event.detail.from];
            newData.splice(event.detail.from, 1);
            newData.splice(event.detail.to, 0, movedRow);

            // Set the new data for the table and redraw it
            table.rows().data(newData).draw();
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

The data is fetched at my vuex store and passed to the component through a computed propery:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const state = {
    orders: [],
};

const actions = {
    async fetchOrders({ commit }) {
        const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:4000/api/v1/deliveries/?limit=15&page=1');
        commit('setOrders', response.data.data.deliveries)
    },
};

const mutations = {
    setOrders(state, orders) {
        state.orders = orders;
    },
};

const getters = {};

export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state,
    getters,
    mutations,
    actions,
};
```

I would like to drag and drop the rows while changing the array position at the store but at my `onRowReorder()` function event.target is undefined. Any help is welcome.